# Extract birthdate of item

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

As an absolute beginner to SPARQL and Wikidata I can't seem to figure out how to extract an attribute of a single entry. Ex:

Find the birthdate of Alan Turing

Can anyone help me out how to do this using the Wikidata Query Service? (query.wikidata.org)

Comment: Pseudo query: `select ?bd where {Alan_Turing birthDate ?bd}` - the rest is up to you, SPARQL tutorials are online, Wikidata datamodel is online, Wikidata SPARQL examples are online, The Wikidata entry for Alan Turing is online.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For future reference: this is what worked for me: `select ?bd where {wd:Q7251 wdt:P569 ?bd}`

Comment: Great: for future, the Wikidata query form provides some kind of autocompletion in case you don't know the entitu URIs, i.e. you ca write `wd:Alan_` and then press `ctrl + space` - see what happens. Same for `wdt:birth` and then `ctrl + space`  - `wd:` namespace used for the instance data  and `wdt:` for schema

Comment: ah, and you found the answer. Feel free to post it as an answer here. And don't forget to accept it. Cheers